# Converting to PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Many thanks for reading my post.

I am fairly new to PHP. I have been working on a project for a while now that uses mysqli and I am trying to convert it to using PDO. In my current set up I have a database class. But I have read on and off that when using PDO, its pointless or at least not necessary to have a database class when using PDO. I wanted to get some opinions on this. I know its a general question but I want to make sure that as I convert my site, I am proceeding in the right way.

Many thanks

Ok so here is the most basic example of my first stumbling block. Please try not to laugh too hard...look at this

```
  try {

  $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=app', 'root', 'fidelio');
  $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    } catch(PDOException $e){

    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
 }

  $name = "pdotest";
  $message = "Test message";
  $sql = "INSERT INTO guestbook (name, message, posted) VALUES (?, ?, NOW())";
  $query = $handler->prepare($sql);
  $query->execute(array($name, $message));
```

This works.

But why does this not work....

```
  class Database {


   private $handler;

    function Connect() {
    $db_host = "localhost";
    $db_name = "app";
    $db_user = "root";
    $db_pass = "fidelio";
    try {
        $this->handler = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $db_host . ";dbname=" . $db_name,  $db_user, $db_pass);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die($e);
    }
}
```

}

```
database = new Database;
$name = "pdotest";
$message = "Test message";
$sql = "INSERT INTO guestbook (name, message, posted) VALUES (?, ?, NOW())";
$database->handler->prepare($sql);
database->execute(array($name, $message));
```

Comment: It's true that it's not *necessary*, however having an abstraction layer is a very good idea. Think of how much time you could've saved converting your site from `mysqli` to `PDO` if all you had to change was a wrapper class.

Comment: What does your database class do exactly? the PDO is a class itself, and it can perform most tasks of course, so another class wrapping it is not *mandatory*, but if you have it well structured it can make the development easier, more comfortable, and avoid repeating code ... sounds to me like some keys to `OOP`

Comment: PDO already is a class with a fairly minimal and decent API. There's no real point in abstracting it any further with another wrapper. Having said that, it *does* give you a little more flexibility if you were to wrap it, for instance you could delay the actual database connection until something actually queried the database. Whether this is useful really depends on your particular needs.

Comment: h2ooooooo, Many thanks. As it stands, using mysqli, I do have a database class (I think its not that clear the way I wrote my post above). This class connects to the database etc. So this is the first port of call in my conversion. I was simply going to convert all the mysqli in this class to PDO. Something that confuses me is that on SOF, some posts use class Database extends PDO and others just class Database. Based on PDO being a class surely it should be the former?

Comment: Extending PDO is almost always a bad idea. One have to have extremely clear understanding on what are they doing. Most PHP users don't.

Comment: @GhostRider Not nessesarily. When your DB layer *extends* PDO you can call PDO functions on the `Database` class. If you don't extend PDO (but rather keep a PDO link inside as a class variable, **which you should** - `private $pdo`) then you can define your own methods (eg. `fetchRow` and `fetchRows`).

Comment: Common sense, I am glad you chimed in. I have read a lot of your stuff on other comments and found it very helpful. If you were not to have database class (and this will sound like a stupid question as its basic), where do you put your database connection - do you have it in every file that accesses the database?

Comment: Ok so here is the most basic example of my first stumbling block. Please try not to laugh too hard...

Comment: That's very basic matter, irrelevant to that class stuff. Programming is a thing that fights repetitions. Thus, doing something *in every file* is a sin against it. Of course connection have to be done only once, and then that entity that bears once opened connection (be it mysql resource, PDO instance or a dedicated database class instance), have to be passed around whole application. Most common setup is a simple connection code that is included in other files

Comment: first of all, [don't die!](http://phpdelusions.net/delusion/try-catch) don't use try catch only to die - that's disgusting and superfluous.

Comment: second, I see no call to connect() method. if you want a method to be performed automatically at class instantion, call it `__construct()`, not connect()

Comment: You're not calling `database->connect...` so you never have a connection made in your example.

Comment: third, `$database->handler` would never work as you defined it private. Honestly, judging by this code, I would rather suggest you to refrain from writing your own wrappers for a while

Comment: OK, why is that? Also, why doesn't this database class work...again, said with my flame suit on...

Comment: Yes, I agree I am too inexperienced to be delving into writing my own classes in the setting of PDO. Your comments are helpful, thank you, (all of you)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly $handler is private, you cannot access them directly

Secondly you forgot to use $database->Connect();

```
class Database {
  .....
  public function getHandler() {
    return $this->handler;
  }
}

$database = new Database;
$database->Connect();
$name = "pdotest";
$message = "Test message";
$sql = "INSERT INTO guestbook (name, message, posted) VALUES (?, ?, NOW())";

$database->getHandler()->prepare($sql);
$database->getHandler()->execute(array($name, $message));
```

note getHandler() function.

As "@Your Common Sense" said, note that Connect function should be called only once - so for this you can call this function in class constructor.

You can call Connect() function in class constructor __construct()

```
class Database {
  .....
   /**
    * Class constructor called when creating new object
    */
   public function __construct() {
       $this->Connect();
   }
}
```

Comment: @GhostRider note that you should call `Connect()` only **once** in all your aplication